# html5 audio tag with playlist

Tags: javascript, html, playlist

I used the html5 audio tag to have an player and I'm trying to play more then one song.

```
<audio id="mp3player" type="audio/mp3" autoplay="true" controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" src='#'>
            Your browser doesn't support the html5 audio tag.
```

I started a mp3 file by:

```
music=document.getElementById("mp3player");
musik.src='mp3/me1.mp3';
```

The problem is that is that I want to use a playlist. Is there something like a m3u playlist. I also found somthing with an music.onend but I didn't find a documention neither did it work for me? Any suggestions.

Comment: function playnextsong(id){
 //alert(PLAYLIST[id].id)
 Musik.src='mp3/'+PLAYLIST[id].id+'.mp3';
} for(z in PLAYLIST)
{
  playnextsong(PLAYLIST.length-z-1);
  alert('ready?');
}

Comment: i need a function that replaces the alert('ready') so the scripts knows that player is ready for the next file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playlist with <audio> JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506685/playlist-with-audio-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event listeners using vanilla JS or your favorite JS library to trigger the nextsong function.

See [Media Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement), specifically the `ended` event.

Comment: i figure that there is no easy way, without a js library

Comment: JS libraries help make cross-browser event listening easy, but if you only care about FF/Webkit/IE8(?)+, just use vanilla JS https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Listening_to_events

Comment: The link is dead, here's a newer one: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp

Comment: Fixed the link, mdn > w3schools