# Playlist with <audio> JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I'm creating a personal small website and I want to play some songs on it. What I've tried to do is the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var i=1;
var nextSong= "";
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audio');
audioPlayer.onended = function(){
    i++
    nextSong = "Music/"+i+".mp3";
    audioPlayer.src = nextSong;
    audioPLayer.load();
    audioPlayer.play();
    if(i == 37) // this is the end of the songs.
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    
}
</script>
<audio id="audio"  src="Music/1.mp3"controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"   align=""> </audio>
```

However, I can't get this to work. It just plays the first song and doesn't execute the JS. I've tried alerting the state of `i` for example but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: please post any relevant message you see in the javascript console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var i=1;
var nextSong= "";
function setup() {
    document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener('ended', function(){
        i++;
        nextSong = "Music/"+i+".mp3";
        audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audio');
        audioPlayer.src = nextSong;
        audioPLayer.load();
        audioPlayer.play();
        if(i == 37) // this is the end of the songs.
        {
            i = 1;
        }
        }, false);
}
</script>
<body onLoad="setup();">
<audio id="audio"  src="Music/1.mp3"controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay"   align=""> </audio>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Amendment needed on this answer. You need to also identify the audio player, otherwise this won't work...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setup() {
    var i=1;
    var nextSong= "";
    audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audio');
    document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener('ended', function(){
        i=i+1;
        nextSong = "m"+i+".mp3";
        audioPlayer.src = nextSong;
        audioPlayer.load();
        audioPlayer.play();     
        }, false);

}
</script>
<body onLoad="setup();">
<audio id="audio"  src="m1.mp3" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" align=""> </audio>
</body>
```

Answer (score -3):

var i=1; var nextSong= ""; function setup() { document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener('ended', function(){ i++; nextSong = "Music/"+i+".mp3"; audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audio'); audioPlayer.src = nextSong; audioPLayer.load(); audioPlayer.play(); if(i == 37) // this is the end of the songs. { i = 1; } }, false); }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).