# How do I loop through a list of songs without all the songs playing simultaneously (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, loops, audio, foreach

I have a list of audio tags containing songs in my HTML document:

```
<div class="pop">
                <p>Pop</p>
                <!--Pop Songs-->
                <audio src="./Pop/We Don't Talk Anymore - Charlie Puth feat. Selena Gomez.mp3"></audio>
                <audio src="./Pop/Senorita - Camila Cabello feat. Shawn Mendes.mp3"></audio>
                <audio src="./Pop/Sucker - Jonas Brother.mp3"></audio>
                <audio src="./Pop/Sunflower - Post Malone feat. Swae Lee.mp3"></audio>
                <audio src="./Pop/No Brainer - DJ Khaled feat. Justin Bieber, Quavo, Chance The Rapper.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

My objective is to loop through them (play each individual song) using Javascript. The issue I keep running into is that all the songs are being played simultaneously, and not each track being played individually, one after the other, like I want it to. How can I fix this?

This the JS code I previously tried, but as I mentioned, all the songs in the list are played simultaneously, which I don't want:

```
const popSongs = document.querySelectorAll(".pop audio");

popSongs.forEach(song => {
    song.play();
})
```

Comment: You're looping through each song and telling them to play, so... that's what happens. There's no surprise. What have you tried to get what you want?

Comment: That exact code, but all the songs play at once

Comment: There is no time between each song, so they play at the same time.

Comment: Okay, but you do see the problem there, right? You're telling all of them to play at the same time, so that's what they're doing. That's all you attempted?

Comment: But if each song has a different time length, how would I edit the code to accommodate each time length of the songs without sounding repetitive?

Comment: Use `onended` event on the audio node.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [playlist with <audio> JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506685/playlist-with-audio-javascript)

Comment: Using `for await`. i.e: https://exploringjs.com/es2018-es2019/ch_asynchronous-iteration.html#for-await-of-and-rejections

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to figure out what the length of all songs are and set a timer or anything. Simply use the [`ended` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event).

```
// Get All Songs
const popSongs = document.querySelectorAll(".pop audio");

// For Each Song
popSongs.forEach((song, songIndex) => {

// Get the Next Song
let nextSong = popSongs[ songIndex === popSongs.length - 1 ? 0 : ++songIndex  ];

// When Current Song Ends
song.addEventListener("ended", function() {

//Play the Next Song
  nextSong.play();

  });
});

// Play first song
popSongs[0].play();
```

Comment: @zfrish is right!  You can check how the ended event works here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp