# How can i play the selected songs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this little html text where I can choose some songs I want to listen to.
How is it that from here I can make pressing the Play button, my selected songs play one after the other. In other words, by order and the second only starts after the first is finished.
Thanks
´

NEW HTML AND SCRIPT

```
<table id="tblsounds">
<tr>
<td><input id="chk1"  type="checkbox" value="1" /><label for="chk01">Song nº 1</label></td>
</tr>
<td><input id="chk2"  type="checkbox" value="2" /><label for="chk02">Song nº 2</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="chk3"  type="checkbox" value="3" /><label for="chk03">Song nº 3</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="chk4"  type="checkbox" value="4" /><label for="chk04">Song nº 4</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="chk5"  type="checkbox" value="5" /><label for="chk05">Song nº 5</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="chk6"  type="checkbox" value="6" /><label for="chk06">Song nº 6</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="chk7"  type="checkbox" value="7" /><label for="chk07">Song nº 7</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="chk8"  type="checkbox" value="8" /><label for="chk08">Song nº 8</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="chk9"  type="checkbox" value="9" /><label for="chk09">Song nº 9</label></td>
</tr>

<br><br>
```

```
</table>
 
 
<input type = "button" value = "Get" onclick = "GetSelected()" />

    <button onClick="window.location.reload();">Remake your Playlist</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function GetSelected() {
        //Create an Array.
        var selected = new Array();
 
        //Reference the Table.
        var tblsounds = document.getElementById("tblsounds");
 
        //Reference all the CheckBoxes in Table.
        var chks = tblsounds.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
 
        // Loop and push the checked CheckBox value in Array.
        for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
            if (chks[i].checked) {
                selected.push(chks[i].value);
            }
        }
 
        //Display the selected CheckBox values.
        if (selected.length > 0) {
            alert("Selected values: " + selected.join(","));
        }
    };
</script>

Like this i get a array as result.

https://codepen.io/luis-pedro-the-sans/pen/rNmLYRp
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [playlist with <audio> JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506685/playlist-with-audio-javascript)

Comment: No. I can't play a selecction. it only play one music

Comment: The question I posted should guide you in the right direction. It's just the matter of stopping the audio and making an array out of your selection. If it doesn't help, please let me know and I'll post the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your way of first forcing people to think and only then giving the answer. I tried. I've tried it in several ways but I can't figure out how to get the click sequence or the choices. I appreciate your help. And the promise remains that I will apply myself more in the coming times to deepen my knowledge, which is still very little. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show some JavaScript code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: ```<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {

  $("#play_button").click(function() {
    var selected_items = $("#playlist td input:checked");

    if (selected_items.length == 0) {
      alert("Não foi seleccionada nada.");
    } else {

      var song = [];
     
      selected_items.each(function() {
        song.push($(this).data("song"));
       


      })
          song.forEach(e => new Audio(e).play());


    }
  });

Comment: Doesn't look too bad :) but in order to keep the order, you'd need to take action on checkbox click. How about adding to an array whenever a checkbox is being clicked? And perhaps removing an item from it when checkbox gets unchecked.

Comment: You're tough. I am going to try. extract values from the array I have seen in other posts how to do it. How to use them afterwards......it's more difficult. and then put it all together......

Comment: Yes, what you're trying to do is not easy. But if you approach it step by step, it'll be doable. Let's start from just having these file names in an array.

Comment: uff. I no longer have a head. I'm blocked. Please a help.

Comment: $("input:checkbox[name=type]:checked").each(function(){
    yourArray.push($(this).val());
});

Comment: It works. I get an array. But now is "THE PART". How can i use this result?

Comment: Why dont you create a codepen with your code so people could help more effectively? https://codepen.io/ Also, to play one song after the other you'll need to listen on the audio's on('ended')  `event` to schedule/start the next song  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#media

Comment: i'm sorry but i give up. I would love some help with the missing code. I'm to noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things to take into account. I prepared an updated code for you, but please try to understand what is going on there. Let's start from the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Playlist</title>
    <script src="playlist.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="tblsounds">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="sound/1.mp3">
                    Song nº 1
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="sound/2.mp3">
                    Song nº 2
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="sound/3.mp3">
                    Song nº 3
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="sound/4.mp3">
                    Song nº 4
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="sound/5.mp3">
                    Song nº 5
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="sound/6.mp3">
                    Song nº 6
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="sound/7.mp3">
                    Song nº 7
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="sound/8.mp3">
                    Song nº 8
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="sound/9.mp3">
                    Song nº 9
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="clear" type="button">
        Remake your Playlist
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing too fancy, I wrapped the checkboxes with their `<label>` to overcome the need of using `id`. Also, I'm having the path to the file as the `value`, because we're gonna use it to keep track which song is currently playing. Just one of the ways to do it. As you can see, I'm keeping the audio in a `sound/` folder, so please update the values if you're gonna keep the audio files elsewhere.

Now, the harder part. Here's the updated JavaScript in `playlist.js` file with comments:

```js
'use strict';

const audio = new Audio();
const playlist = [];

document.getElementById('tblsounds').addEventListener('click', event => {
    const isCheckbox = event.target.matches('input[type=checkbox]');

    if (!isCheckbox) return;

    const songFileName = event.target.value;

    if (event.target.checked) {
        // Adding the song to the playlist
        playlist.push(songFileName);

        if (playlist.length === 1) {
            audio.src = songFileName;
            audio.play();
        }
    } else {
        // Removing the song from the playlist
        const songIndex = playlist.indexOf(songFileName);

        if (songIndex >= 0) {
            const audioSrc = audio.getAttribute('src');

            if (audioSrc === songFileName) {
                audio.pause();

                const nextSongIndex = songIndex + 1;

                if (nextSongIndex < playlist.length) {
                    audio.src = playlist[nextSongIndex];
                    audio.play();
                }
            }

            playlist.splice(songIndex, 1);
        }
    }
});

document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', () => {
    // Clear all checkboxes
    document.getElementById('tblsounds').querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.checked = false;
    });

    // Empty the playlist
    playlist.splice(0, playlist.length);

    audio.pause();
});

audio.addEventListener('ended', event => {
    // Play the next song if available
    const audioSrc = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('src');
    const playlistIndex = playlist.indexOf(audioSrc);

    if (playlistIndex >= 0) {
        const nextSongIndex = playlistIndex + 1;

        if (nextSongIndex < playlist.length) {
            audio.src = playlist[nextSongIndex];
            audio.play();
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, we keep updating the content of the `playlist` array when interacting with the checkboxes. It plays the next song after the current one is finished, but only if there's a next song in the playlist.

I know we usually don't post full solutions on Stack Overflow, but since you're a beginner and you want to do something quite involved (and interesting!), I decided to help you with it. I hope you'll learn from it :)

Comment: Sorry but one more thing. how to start playing songs after clicking a START button and not after selecting the first box. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to refactor it yourself?

Comment: I know I have to add something like:
document.getElementById('playbutton').addEventListener('click', () => {
but I can't get it to touch it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense for me to do it, because playlist behavior has some edge cases, which I'd need to decide myself on how to handle them. Also, I already went too far by writing the fully functional feature for you. This is not what we do on Stack Overflow. You want to create something too advanced for your current skillset, so you should either hire some to do it for you, or spend some time learning and then create it.